# Why the console log doesn't appear in my function?

Tags: react-native, console

I'm trying to see the console log of this state inside the function "RenderX()", but nothing happens. When I tried in another function, like in render function or inside the componentWillMount, display normally. Anyone  has seen this problem before?

```
export default class CapaMagazine extends Component {

    state = { capa: [this.props.capa.edicaoID] };

    componentWillMount() {
        Firebase.name

        const db = firebase.firestore();

        db.collection('revista_capa').get().then((result) => {
            result.forEach((doc) => {
                if (this.state, '==', doc.data().edicaoID) {
                    this.setState({ capa: doc.data() })
                }
            });
        });
    }

    funcaoX(){
        console.log(this.state);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `funcaoX = () => console.log(this.state);`

Comment: `this` is in local scope and `state` is outside of that scope. You can use an arrow function or bind your method in the constructor. Similar issue explained here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: @wdm I tried this one and nothing happens. It's weird because I have another file with the same code and works without any troubles.

Comment: @wdm I will try this way using the constructor. Wait a second

Comment: Where are you calling `funcaoX()`? I don't see it being called in the code you posted.

Comment: I'll call inside this content. The real code of "funcaoX" is this: 
 `funcaoX() {
  const result = Object.values(this.state);
  return result.map(capa =>
   <CapaDetail key={capa.edicaoID} capa={capa} />
  );
 }`
And inside the content tag I'll put:  `<View>{this.funcaoX()}</View> `

Comment: @wdm I didn't get any callback even if I put the bind method in my constructor. I'm trying to get a simple console.log like `console.log("lalalala"),` in a function before the render and I can't get anything. I really don't know what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried just calling from inside `render` like this: `render() { this.funcaoX(); return { ... }` to see if you get the `console.log` at least.